# How to load data form wicket page to highchart?

Tags: javascript, database, wicket

I am create a bar chart using highchart library.

The portion of sample coding is

```
series: [{           
    name: 'foo',
    data: [10000, 60000, 90000, 14000, 18000, 21000, 25000, 26000, 23000, 18000, 13000, 9000]
}]
```

How do I get these data value from wicket page?

Comment: Where do you want to put this JavaScript? In the header?

Comment: it is very easy to integrated high chart with wicketpage.you refer this site http://code.google.com/p/wicket-charts/

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to integrate highchart with wicket.
Refer the following site http://code.google.com/p/wicket-charts/